# Модальное окно без привязки по ID (к ссылке, имени, классу)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть простое модальное окно (два окна)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы окна открывались без привязки к классу, id или ссылке?:

```
<a href="#modal1"></a>
<a href="#modal2"></a>
```

Comment: Отвязаться не очень то и получится, содержимое окон может быть разным - картинка, форма, карта, и т.д. Отвязаться получится если у Вас только одно модальное окно (чего Вы видимо и добиваетесь), а содержимое окна Вы передаете САМИ, формируя его, например, через AJAX или поднимая еще откуда-нибудь со страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Надо запомнить одну важную вещь ID уникальный идентификатор и на странице может быть один

`id="myBtn"` - заменил на `class="myBtn"` и тоже самое и с `id="myModal"` который превратил `class`

В примере ниже, я сделал просто пример, без цикла... `Сам был новичком - помню, путался не понимал, что за циклы и зачем`

Ниже приведу вторым вариантом абстрактный пример с циклом. что-бы было понятней...

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn[0].onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
//обрати внимание на индексы [N] 
span[0].onclick = function() {
  modal[0].style.display = "none";
}
//=========================================================
// мои изменения
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn[1].onclick = function() {
  modal[1].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[1].onclick = function() {
  modal[1].style.display = "none";
}
//==========================================
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div  class="modal myModal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div  class="modal myModal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Второй вариант с циклом

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

// Создаем цикл. берем любой элемент в данном случае не имеет особого значения

for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
  // и тут определяем что при нажатии на btn[i]
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // должно присвоиться css значение элементу с темже индексом
    modal[i].style.background = 'red'
  })
  // а тут обратный ход
  span[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal[i].style.background = 'grey'
  })
}
```

```css
button,
div,
span {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal_1</button>
<div class="myModal">myModal_1</div>
<span>close_1</span>
<!--=======================================-->
<br/>
<button class="myBtn">Open Modal_2</button>
<div class="myModal">myModal_2</div>
<span>close_2</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так без привязки ... хотя на самом деле всё равно привязан по id а вот закрывать надо уже думать как [demo](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XqxxLb?editors=0100)

это мой вариант

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.item {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s
}

.item a {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  dispkay: block;
}

div:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<a href="#item1">открыть окно 1</a>
<a href="#item2">открыть окно 2</a>
<a href="#item3">открыть окно 3</a>

<div id="item1" class="item">
  <a href="#">&#10006;</a> окно 1
</div>
<div id="item2" class="item">
  <a href="#">&#10006;</a> окно 2
</div>
<div id="item3" class="item">
  <a href="#">&#10006;</a> окно 3
</div>
```